# Convert String Array to JSON or 2D Array SWIFT

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift

I currently have a NSMutableArray "localArray" and I am trying to create that into a JSON Array or a 2D Array. I get this data my creating a database and running a query using a for loop on the database.

```
{
Food,
Burger,
3.99,
1.25,
POP,
Crush,
1.99,
.89,
and more.
}
```

The reason why I am looking for a JSON or 2d Array is I want to hold the data in the localArray in such a way that I can identify by type and then do something like `.valueForKey("Name")` or `.valurForKey("Price")` and add that to my tableview's cell text label or labels.

```
{
  {
  Type Food,
  Name Burger,
  Price 3.99,
  Cost 1.25,
  },
  { 
  Type POP,
  Name Crush,
  Price 1.99,
  Cost .89,
  },
  and more
}
```

I have already tried JSONSerialization, but that failed and also tried 2d Array but no luck.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

This is how I Query and add the data to localArray

```
let queryType = data.select(ada, code, name, proof, size, case_size, price)
        .filter(bevType == type)

    let rows = Array(queryType)

    for row in rows{
        let name = row[self.name]
        let type = row[self.type]
        let cost = row[self.cost]
        let price = row[self.price]


        localArray.addObject(name)
        localArray.addObject(type)
        localArray.addObject(cost)
        localArray.addObject(price)

    }
```

Comment: what data format does your database return?

Comment: Its really hard to tell because I can never get the table to print. Its a sqlite3 db in swift. I can only get the result to print after i do a query in a for loop.

Comment: @Dereck If you have trouble looking at your table contents in Swift, you can use an app like [SQLite browser](http://sqlitebrowser.org) to visualize it. It can help you understand how your table is structured. Then you will be able to debug your code more efficiently.

Comment: I know how my data looks since I am inserting it in and when I do queries it does give me what I am looking for! But having hard time getting the data in a format explained above. So I can set the data from the queries to the table view controller in my project!

Comment: Well, you said "Its really hard to tell" in the comment before when you were asked what is the format of your database. Nevermind.

Comment: Sorry! I just want to get the data out of the query in a certain format! So I can set data to my table view and labels! 
Do you have any idea on how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself by creating a dictionary.

```
    for row in rows{
        var rDict: Dictionary = [String: String]()
        rDict["Name"] = row[self.name]
        rDict["Type"] = row[self.type]
        rDict["Cost"] = row[self.cost]
        rDict["Price"] = row[self.price]

        localArray.addObject(rDict)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If fields are always repeating in count of 4, you can try doing this:

```
var array = [[String: AnyObject]]() 
for var i = 0 ; i < array.count ; i += 4 {
    var k = 0
    var dict = [String: AnyObject]
    dict["Type"] = array[i + k++]
    dict["Name"] = array[i + k++]
    dict["Price"] = array[i + k++]
    dict["Cost"] = array[i + k]
    array.append(dict)
}
```

Then extract dictionary from this swift array and use same keys to extract data from dictionary to be used in your cell like

```
let dict = array[indexPath.row]
cell.title = dict["Name"]
```

Comment: When i do array [i + k++] it gives me error that "Could not find an overload for '+' that accepts the supplied arguments"